# How are TOPICS managed in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

Is every topic in Apache Kafka an independent queue or there is a single queue which has all topics or a large number of topics are distributed over a lesser number of queues?

In other words, `is 1 Topic = 1 Queue`?

Or, how does Kafka maintain each topic internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kafka, each topic is a single and logical distributed commit-log (i.e an append-only file).

Each topic is splitted into a number of partitions distributed through your cluster. The number of partitions can be increased dynamically.

A partition is physically stored on filesystem. A partition must fit entirely in one broker (a machine in a Kafka cluster).

In addition, you can have multiple partitions of a same topic on one broker.

Then partitions are themselve split into a number of segment files (default a segment has a size of 1GB)

To illustrate this, you can create a topic as bellow :

**Create a new topic 'test'**

```
     $ > ./kafka-topics --create --topic test --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --zookeeper localhost:2181
     Created topic "test".
```

**List kafka partitions** (one folder per partition)

```
     $ > ls /tmp/kafka-logs | grep test
      test-0
      test-1
      test-2
```

**List segment files for each partition**

```
 $ > ls -sh /tmp/kafka-logs/test* 
     /tmp/kafka-logs/test-0:
     total 0
     0 00000000000000000000.index  0 00000000000000000000.log

     /tmp/kafka-logs/test-1:
     total 4,0K
     0 00000000000000000000.index  4,0K 00000000000000000000.log

     /tmp/kafka-logs/test-2:
     total 4,0K
     0 00000000000000000000.index  4,0K 00000000000000000000.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Topic has partitions. Each partition is a queue. Items in each partition are processed in sequential order. You publish to a Topic and depending upon partition logic, the messages are published to partitions. By default round robin distribution is used, but is configurable.

Comment: I think this is how the topic logs are configured, not the topic itself. Could you please verify this once more. @superaghu

Comment: @divyesh - what do you mean by topic logs, Kafka do not have such concept. The info I presented is about Topics